# CSS Grid collapse element when resizing and make disappear

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid, grid-layout

I have a row of 3 columns.

When I resize the page I would like the elements to keep their width but if any element cant fit the adjusted screen size then I would like it to drop down to the next row.

I am trying to do this with css grid.

[JSBin Link](https://jsbin.com/fiqocag/edit?html,output)

My styling is as follows

```
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 30% 40%;
    grid-gap: 1em;
  }
```

Comment: Then you don't want a grid, consider flexbox instead

Answer (score 1):

As JTS mentioned, you need to use media queries.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:900px) {
      .wrapper {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
          grid-gap: 1em;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:576px) {
      .wrapper {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 100%;
          grid-gap: 1em;
        }
    }
```

You can check bootstrap's standard breakpoints and create your own based on that
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

You can check the updated JS Bin code

https://jsbin.com/bulaqigexi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue at one point on theelectronichandbook.tech here is what I used. The @media statement can vary on your projected viewports (ie. Iphone X, IPod touch 2g, 8k 120" tv, etc.)

If that is too confusing, here is a much more suitable code for the job which I made to based off of the provided JSbin.

```css
.wrapper>div:nth-child(1) {
    width:4em;
}
.wrapper>div:nth-child(2) {
    width:8em;
}
.wrapper>div:nth-child(3) {
    width:16em;
}
.wrapper>div:nth-child(4) {
    width:32em;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper>div {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>What is this story?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
            <h1>1</h1>
            F******t w***n love Eminem. "Chicka, chicka, chicka, S**m S***y, I'm sick of him. Look at him, walkin' around, g******' his y**-****-***t. F*****n' the y**-****-**o," "Yeah, but he's so cute though.". Yeah, I probably got a couple of s****s up in my head loose. But no worse than what's goin' on in your parents' bedrooms.
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>2</h1>
            Will the real S**m S***y please stand up?. I repeat, will the real S**m S***y please stand up?. We're gonna have a problem here. Y'all act like you never seen a w**** ****** before. Jaws all on the floor like P** like T**** just burst in the door. And started whoopin' her a** worse than before.
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>3</h1>
            I'm S**m S***y, yes, I'm the real S***y. All you other S**m S****s are just imitating. So won't the real S**m S****s please stand up. Please stand up, please stand up?. 'Cause I'm Slim Shady, yes, I'm the real S***y. All you other S**m S****s are just imitating. So won't the real S**m S***y please stand up. Please stand up, please stand up?
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>4</h1>
            My tea's gone cold. I'm wondering why I got out of bed at all. The morning rain clouds up my window. And I can't see at all. And even if I could it'd all be gray. But your picture on my wall. It reminds me that it's not so bad, it's not so bad.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user12414493 @Michael_B I just looked over the code and am interested in knowing weather you would like each odd child element to have alternated color or each row to have alternated color. If it is each row of elements let me know and I will write something that will do such a task. I decided that the code in the test HTML content was not appropriate for stack-overflow so I replaced it with `*`.